# Popup window and context menu

Tags: winforms, winapi, popup

I am using the ToolStripDropDown to host the user control as the pop-up window. The problem is when a context menu strip is displayed from within this pop-up window, the pop-up itself closes in the moment the context menu opens.
I have tried to subclass the ContextMenuStrip and added WS_EX_NOACTIVATE to CreateParams but nothing changed. First I thought that there is no way to do this since it is common behavior but then I tried to put a TextBox class onto the pop-up user control and invoke the Edit control context menu - and the parent pop-up window did not close. 
What am I missing?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you are asking.  I understand the concept of hosting a UserControl within a ToolStripDropDown.  What I'm not sure about is how a pop-up window and context menu works into this.  More deets please?  Or some code?

Comment: I am using the ToolStripDropDown in the way as described in this article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/SuperContextMenu.aspx.
The hosted UserControl has the ContextMenuStrip property set to a context menu which is shown on right mouse button click but the ToolStripDropDown pop-up window is closed just in the moment the context menu is shown.

Comment: I have just found a mysterious thing. When I use the ContextMenuStrip its activation closes the parent ToolStripDropDown, but when I use the ContextMenu it does not.
What is a difference between these two classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similary Problem. On my UserControll was a toolstrip. When I pressed the toolsstripdropdownbutton the dropdown was shown but the popup disapeared.
The reason was that popup.Autoclose was true. After Setting to false the Popup is not closed any more.

```
        ToolStripDropDown popup = new ToolStripDropDown();
        popup.AutoClose = false;         //Set to FALSE
        popup.Margin = Padding.Empty;
        popup.Padding = Padding.Empty;
        ToolStripControlHost host = new ToolStripControlHost(userControl1);
        host.Margin = Padding.Empty;
        host.Padding = Padding.Empty;
        popup.Items.Add(host);
        popup.Show(button1, new Point(100,100));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actual Solution should be the one in Martin's final comment:
Use ContextMenu Instead of ContextMenuStrip
That one worked for me, and the ToolStripDropDown no longer closes by itself when right clicking one of its content controls, like it should. We still need it to AutoClose, disabling AutoClose on ToolStripDropDown will do bad things, it is supposed to close on losing focus. Example: open any other app window, and the ToolStripDropDown will continue to appear on top